# python to MySQL within pythonAnywhere

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.4, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to enter data from python 3.4 into a MySQL database, with both of these entities being within pythonAnywhere.  In other words, I'm writing a python 3.4 program in pythonAnywhere and need to connect to a MySQL db also within pythonAnywhere.  I've checked other answers here and haven't quite figured it out.  I've tried the ( -u -h -p) syntax mentioned by a few posts, but I'm not sure if that is just for gaining access from outside of pythonAnywhere.
 Any help would be appreciated.

++++++++++++++++++++

## Actually I figured it out (with kudos to Tony Darnell at the Scripting MySQL website, from whom I plagiarized most of this:

```
import MySQLdb

db=MySQLdb.connect(
    host='Your_User_Name.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
    user='Your_User_Name',
    passwd='Your_pythonAnywhere_password',
    db='Your_User_Name$Your_Data_Base')
```

## everything above starting with 'Your' refers to you personal account info with pythonanywhere

## everything else gets listed exactly as shown.  Watch that $ that follows your user name as part of the database name (db = etc.)

```
cursor = db.cursor ()
```

## execute the SQL query using execute() method.

```
cursor.execute ("Enter any MySQL query here. use the quotes. no semi-colon")
```

## fetch a single row from query using fetchone() method.

```
row = cursor.fetchone ()
print(row)
```

## fetch all the rest of the query using fetchall() method

```
data = cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
```

## close the cursor object

```
cursor.close ()
```

## close the connection

```
db.close ()
```